# How to access the value of an input field by its value and name attribute using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to select an input:
`<input id="tb-radio-gym_custom_radio-10ce67e3" type="radio" value="OUI" name="form_fields[gym_custom_radio]" data-price-inc="0" checked="checked">`

I'd like to select it, by his name and value.
The id is random so i can't select like this.

I don't know how to select it with : value="OUI" and name="form_fields[gym_custom_radio]"

When i can select this input, i'd like to hide it then.
It can be JS or Jquery, i tried but i can't do it, so thank you for your help !!

Comment: $('input[value="OUI"][name="form_fields[gym_custom_radio]"]')  - for jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Use an [*Attribute Selector*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) with multiple attributes.

```js
const radioButton = document.querySelector(
    'input[name="form_fields[gym_custom_radio]"][value="OUI"]')
```

Make sure you quote the values so you don't run into trouble with the square-brackets in the `name`.

You can use the same selector string with jQuery.

Demo...

```js
const radioButton = document.querySelector(
    'input[name="form_fields[gym_custom_radio]"][value="OUI"]')
    
radioButton.classList.add('active')
console.log('OUI data-price-inc:', radioButton.dataset.priceInc)
```

```css
.active {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px red;
}
```

```html
<input id="tb-radio-gym_custom_radio-10ce67e3" type="radio" value="OUI" name="form_fields[gym_custom_radio]" data-price-inc="0" checked="checked">
<input id="tb-radio-gym_custom_radio-7r7r09r" type="radio" value="NON" name="form_fields[gym_custom_radio]" data-price-inc="1">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i get this error : "TypeError: radioButton is null"

Comment: @seb606 either your element does not look like it does in your question or you are running the JS **before** the element appears in your document. If the latter, please see [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: Thank you Phil, yes i think it's because of this.
I use a reservation calendar, nd as you said, i think the element doesn't appear yet.
I will see with the link you game me, maybe with the "defer attribute".
(if you think it can be good ?)

Comment: I tried like this: 
`document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        const radioButton = document.querySelector('input[name="form_fields[gym_custom_radio]"][value="OUI"][checked="checked"]')
        radioButton.classList.add('cacheInputOui')
console.log('OUI data-price-inc:', radioButton.dataset.priceInc)
        });`
I have no error but nothing happened...

Comment: Do you see the console line with `OUI data-price-inc:`? You should either see that or an error but not _nothing_

Comment: I don't see it, here is the similar page:
https://www.coursdeyoga-94.fr/reservations/
The input i tried to change is after i selected a date and time.

Comment: Your document appear to be updating dynamically. You will need to run the selector script at the appropriate time

Comment: Thank you Phil, yes it's like this but i use a Wordpress plugin and not easy to know where and how i can do this.
(i included the plugin in another page i did with my own code).
I'll try to see with the WP plugin's author.